# PyQt5 Qtablewidget как отлавливать сигнал на изменения в таблице после ее создания и отключать на время повторной генерации таблицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5, pyqt

у меня создается таблица , которая заполняется циклом. self.table.cellChanged[int, int].connect(self.changedRowColumn) вызывается после, для сохранения в словарь произведенных изменений. все работает как надо, но я добавил кнопку перехода на главную, где зачищаю таблицу, но когда заново генерирую таблицу, то self.table.cellChanged[int,int].connect(self.changedRowColumn) уже включена и она записывает всю генерацию таблицы в файл изменений! вопрос в том может как то иначе лучше сохранять изменения в таблице или как то можно отключить этот сигнал на время выполнения до определенного места где он и включится.

Comment: Опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Можно переподключать сигнал при помощи вызова пары disconnect/connect. Можно временно блокировать сигналы при помощи вызова `QObject.blockSignals(bool)`

Comment: спасибо, решил вопрос QObject.blockSignals(bool). работает так, как надо)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin а на qml есть такой блокировщик?

Comment: @eri есть такая конструкция как Connections по ссылке пример использования https://stackoverflow.com/a/44497280/4711135